# What is happening with my sculpt tools/viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, sculpting, selection-tools, masking

I have just finished sculpting the body of my model and moved on to do the hands separately. I joined the objects, remeshed, and checked the normals of the final object. I have cleared masks and looked to see if anyone else has had any problems like this and found nothing. My sculpt tools are inverted, and the hands are grayed out. Clay strips don't seem to work at all, and I have to hold control to inflate.

[image: Without Normals Shown]

[image: With Normals Shown]

I am at a total loss as to what may be happening here. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I have no idea what I did the first time, but i remade the hand and went into sculpt mode and now everything is working fine. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time, but if you have any ideas of what happened the first time I would still like to hear your thoughts. :)

Comment: It looks like you have masked the hand? Alt M to unmask the masked part